# JS: How to make Div's appear on click but not append? Like a tool-tip

Tags: javascript

This is a bit hard for me to explain so I will try my best. I am developing a small game where the character will have 8 skills to attack the enemy players with, and I want to implement a system that when you click upgrade, a sub-menu system pops or appears open and you can choose 1 of 3 skills to upgrade that particular skill to.

The problem I'm having is I pretty much got the design down and implemented, but I'm not quite sure how to make it when I click on a button, the upgrade menu appears where you click.

At the moment I'm just embedding my upgrade-menu DIV's, but I would rather have it where when you click a skill it appears for skill selection, but then goes away after you select your skill, rather than hard-coding itself into the skill itself as seen below.

Whats the best way to go about this? I think my problem is the "appendChild" function, because it makes it "stick" to what i'm applying my DIV's to.

[image]

```js
New=Object.create;

dom = {
 el: function (id){
  return document.getElementById(id);
 },
 setText: function (id,text) {
  this.el(id).innerHTML = text;
 },
 setTextCon: function (id,text){
  this.el(id).innerHTML += text;
 }
}


function upgradeBar() {
  menu("upgradeMenu", "systemMenu");
 }
 
 
 function menu(classID, id) {
  var button = dom.el("skill"); // Apply DIV to THIS location
  var x = document.createElement("div");
  x.setAttribute("class", classID);
  x.setAttribute("id", id);
  button.appendChild(x);
  
 function skills(classID, id, title){
  var circle = dom.el("systemMenu"); // Apply DIV to THIS location
  var x = document.createElement("div");
  x.setAttribute("class", classID);
  x.setAttribute("id", id);
  x.setAttribute("title", title);
  circle.appendChild(x);
//  dom.setText(id, text);
  }
 skills("skills", "attack1", "Strike 1"); 
  skills("skills", "attack2", "Strike 2"); 
 skills("skills", "attack3", "Strike 3");  
}

dom.el("skill").onclick = upgradeBar;
```

```css
.upgradeMenu {
 background-image: url("/home/shawnmusick/Documents/Card Warriors/images/triblack.jpg");
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 50px;
 position: relative;
}

#attack1 {
 background-image: url("");
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 50px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin-left: -10px;
 z-index: 1;
}

#attack2 {
 background-image: url("");
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 50px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin-right: -10px;
 z-index: 1;
}
#attack3 {
 background-image: url("");
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 50px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 margin-left: 23px;
 margin-bottom: -15px;
 z-index: 1;
 
}

.buttons {
 min-width: 80px;
 min-height: 30px;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <title>Arena Brawl</title>
  <meta content="text/html" charset="utf-8"</meta>
  <link href="css/game.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 <body>
      
      <button id="strike" type="button" class="buttons">Strike</button>
       <button id="cure" type="button" class="buttons">Cure</button>
       <button id="defend" type="button" class="buttons">Defend</button>
       <button id="debuff" type="button" class="buttons">Debuff</button>

       <button id="strike2" type="button" class="buttons">Strike2</button>
       <button id="cure2" type="button" class="buttons">Cure2</button>
       <button id="defend2" type="button" class="buttons">Defend2</button>
       <button id="debuff2" type="button" class="buttons">Debuff2</button>
       
       <button id="skill" type="button" class ="buttons" > Upgrade Me </button>
      
      
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks nice. Can you make a working snippet please?

Comment: Do you have a link to a website? I'll add the code there so people can take a look at it.

Comment: How about appending `absolute-positioned` element ?

Comment: Not sure but setting `title` property on `click` may help...

Comment: @user2763154 What??? Yea I do have a website and a server.

Comment: I guess 1 thing I can do is set the skill button itself as the "center" of upgrade pop-up, but I somehow have to get the div "over" or on "top" of the button so they can make their selection?

Comment: Boss, what you say is possible. Still it is unclear.

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question?, create stacksnippets or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate? Not exactly certain what requirement is? At `click` on `"Upgrade Me"`, display eight buttons until zero to three of the buttons have been clicked? Then toggle visibility of eight buttons?

Comment: Okay I added the snippet. There won't be pictures for obvious reasons.

Comment: Currently appending duplicate `id` to `document` when click on circle. What is expected result once one to three circles are clicked? Is user required to click all three circles?  What do you mean by _"it appears for skill selection, but then goes away after you select your skill"_?

Comment: The 3 circles are 1 of 3 selectable skills to upgrade to. He will click on 1 of them only, which will disregard the other 2. For example: If you want to upgrade  "strike 1" to "strike 2", you will select that in the upgrade sub-menu. Then the strike 1 button will vanish completely and be replaced with strike 2.

Comment: I want it where when you have a upgrade point available, you click on the skill you want to upgrade. This will open the sub-menu shown above, where the user will have 3 selectable options. Each skill will have its own unique branch. I want a "hover" type of effect so when its time to upgrade, the radial sub-menu appears or "pops" as you hover over which skill to upgrade.

Comment: User can only select one of the three circles? Then only two circles would be displayed? At hover of circle element the three "skills" options is displayed? Once clicked the three skills options are added to user "skills" object, no other selections available?

Comment: No, once he selects a circle, the entire radial-dial upgrade menu dissappears. So if you notice when you click on "upgrade me", the upgrade system menu opens up and you can select 1 of 3. This should disappear after you made your selection. However the "upgrade me" button, is just a test button.

Comment: The best way I can explain it, is imagine the 3 skill upgrade menu system appears when you hover over 1 of the 8 skills you can select to upgrade. But once you made your selection, it disappears.

Comment: Once one of the eight skills is hovered, user is required to make selection by clicking on one of the three circles?

Comment: Well the way it works is, once you get enough experience, you "level up". You then use your upgrade points to buy skill upgrades. The user will be able to hover over 1 of the 8 skills, (each 8 will have 3 unique skill upgrades to them), reading about what the new skills do, then selects 1 of the 3. Then the upgrade system disappears. Its not "required", its only optional to upgrade when you get the points to do so.

Comment: _"Its not "required"_ User should have option to close the menu if no selection will be made? One one of the buttons is hovered, other  buttons are not able to be hovered until one of the selections of "skills" is made or menu is closed?

Comment: When you hover "out" of the radial-menu, it should close by default.  I think I can put a "x" in their somewhere to also optionally close it.

Comment: _"When you hover "out" of the radial-menu, it should close by default."_ Then there would be two separate hover events? Hover at one of eight buttons displays "upgrade" menu; then how would user immediately be hovering at upgrade menu?, where hovering out of upgrade menu would close menu?

Comment: hovering out in the sense that the mouse leaves the radial menu boundaries, thus closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data-*` attributes to store array, object, or array of objects containing "skills" descriptions, values. At `mouseenter` event at `<button>` element toggle `display` of "Upgrade" `<fieldset>` element; set `disabled` attribute at `button` elements saving for clicked `button` element; remove `mouseeneter` event for all `button` elements;  populate `<input type="button">` elements `.value`, `.title` with values set at clicked `<button>` element `data-*` attribute. At `click` at `<input type="button">` element, push `.value` of element to object referencing current user; set `fieldset` element `display` to `none`, remove current `.value` at `input` elements, add `mouseeneter` event to `button` elements.

```js
function CreateUser(name) {
  name = name.toString();
  if (name === undefined || name == "") {
    throw new Error("CreateUser: name required")
  }
  this.name = "user" + name;
  this.skills = [];

};

var skill = document.getElementById("skill");
var label = skill.querySelector("label");
var opts = skill.querySelectorAll(".options");
var close = document.getElementById("close");
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons");

var user0 = new CreateUser(0);
initSkillsUpgrade("add", user0);

function initSkillsUpgrade(toggleHandler, user) {
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i][toggleHandler + "EventListener"]
    ("mouseenter", handleMouseEnter.bind(buttons[i], user))
  }
}

function handleMouseEnter(user, e) {
  var not = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons:not(#" + e.target.id + ")");
  toggle(not, true);
  toggle(skill);
  initSkillsUpgrade("remove");
  var all = [].slice.call(not).concat(e.target);
  var skills = JSON.parse(e.target.dataset.skills);
  skill.className = "";
  label.innerHTML = "Add a " + e.target.textContent + " skill:";
  skills.forEach(function(opt, index) {
    // alternatively, dynamically create `<input type="button">`
    // elements here, corresponding to `.length` of `skills` array
    if (typeof opt === "object") {
      var key = Object.keys(opt)[0];
      opts[index].title = opt[key];
      opts[index].value = key;
    } else {
      opts[index].title = "Does " + opt + " stuff";
      opts[index].value = opt;
    }

    opts[index].onclick = function(optsEvent) {
      if (user.skills.indexOf(optsEvent.target.value) === -1) {
        user.skills.push(optsEvent.target.value);
        alert(user.name + " added " 
            + optsEvent.target.value 
            + " skill. Current skills: " 
            + JSON.stringify(user.skills));
      } else {
        alert(user.name + " has " 
             + optsEvent.target.value 
             + " skill, select anoter skill. Current skills:" 
             + JSON.stringify(user.skills)
             )
      }
      
      label.innerHTML = "";
      for (var n = 0; n < opts.length; n++) {
        opts[n].value = "";
      }
      toggle(skill);
      toggle(all, false);
      initSkillsUpgrade("add", user);
    }
  });
}

close.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (var n = 0; n < opts.length; n++) {
    opts[n].value = "";
  };
  toggle(skill);
  toggle(buttons, false);
  initSkillsUpgrade("add", user0);
});

function toggle(elems, bool) {
  if (elems.id === "skill") {
    if (elems.className === "closed") {
      elems.className = "";
    } else {
      elems.className = "closed"
    }
    return;
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < elems.length; j++) {
    elems[j].disabled = bool;
  }
}
```

```css
#skill.closed {
  display: none;
}
.buttons {
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Arena Brawl</title>
  <meta content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <!-- object value within `JSON` array at `data-skills` -->
  <button id="strike" type="button" class="buttons" 
    data-skills='[{"strike1":"does strike1 stuff"},
                 "strike2",
                 "strike3"]'>Strike</button>
  <button id="cure" type="button" class="buttons" 
    data-skills='["cure1",
                 "cure2",
                 "cure3"]'>Cure</button>
  <button id="defend" type="button" class="buttons" 
    data-skills='[{"defend1":"does defend1 stuff"},
                 "defend2",
                 "defend3"]'>Defend</button>
  <button id="debuff" type="button" class="buttons" 
    data-skills='["debuff1",
                 "debuff2",
                 "debuff3"]'>Debuff</button>
  <button id="strike2" type="button" class="buttons" 
    data-skills='["strike2a",
                 "strike2b",
                 "strike2c"]'>Strike2</button>
  <button id="cure2" type="button" class="buttons" 
    data-skills='["cure2a",
                 "cure2b",
                 "cure2c"]'>Cure2</button>
  <button id="defend2" type="button" class="buttons" 
    data-skills='["defend2a",
                 "defend2b",
                 "defend2c"]'>Defend2</button>
  <button id="debuff2" type="button" class="buttons" 
    data-skills='[{"debuff2a":"does debuff2a stuff"},
                 "debuff2b",
                 "debuff2c"]'>Debuff2</button>
  <br>
  <fieldset id="skill" class="closed">
    <button id="close">close menu</button>
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <label>Add a skill:</label>
    <input type="button" class="options" value="">
    <input type="button" class="options" value="">
    <input type="button" class="options" value="">
  </fieldset>
  <!--
    <button id="skill" type="button" class="buttons">Upgrade Me</button> 
  -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A very long answer and exactly what I needed. Thank you sir! :)